# How to distribute my android library with no dependencies and conflicts?

Tags: android, maven, android-library

We have developed an Android library and now, we are trying to achieve the best form to distribute it. This library has a lot of third parties dependencies, like Retrofit 2, Dagger 2 and so on. Also, each layer of the app (presentation, domain, data) is a independent module in the Android project. We are publishing our library in Jitpack.

We have tried to integrate this library in all types of project, but always has conflicts. For example, if the project is ancient, the Android Support Library has conflict. In the same way is a project with has dagger 1.

We have tried the examples of [Gradle Dependency Management page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html), like 'force', 'exclude' or 'substitute', but it doesn't work.

Now, we are trying to modifying the pom file with Gradle like this:

```
install {
  repositories.mavenInstaller {
    pom.whenConfigured {pom ->
      pom.dependencies.each { dep ->
        if (dep.groupId == 'me.dm7.barcodescanner' && dep.artifactId == 'zbar' ) {
          dep.optional = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We are modifying the pom file because we have seen that the picasso library has [no dependencies](http://www.methodscount.com/?lib=com.squareup.picasso%3Apicasso%3A2.5.2) when you integrated it. But we don't know how it can achieve it. We think it the optional flag, but we are not sure and how to reach this goal. Could someone explain it?

What is the best way to distribute a Android library and avoid conflicts when this library is integrated in any app?

Comment: Have you looked into what it means to have a "provided" dependency (as opposed to a "compile" dependency)?

Comment: It can be a lot of work and might not be what you are looking for, but a general software design principle which can be used to reduce the amount of packaged dependencies is the dependency inversion principle. Check out this wiki page https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Comment: Another option I have been trying out is for stuff like play-services and support library. Is different flavors using flavorv dimensions. This library project does that https://github.com/remcomokveld/CastNotifications